# If you change the sign of a two tailed test does the p value remain the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

If the results of a t test are reversed are the p values the same?

I am running an experiment:

Treatment: sample size - 5k and metric value - 0.57 Control: sample size - 5k and metric value - 0.62

The lift from the control to the treatment is -0.05 with a p value of 0.013. So it’s significant.

What if I flipped the treatment and control so now I have:

Treatment: sample size - 5k and metric value - 0.62 Control: sample size - 5k and metric value - 0.57

The lift from control to treatment is 0.05 but does the p value stay the same?

Comment: What would you consider your null and alternative hypotheses? Depending on the answer, I could see the p-value changing or remaining the same.

Comment: It is a two tailed test so I assume it would stay the same. If its one tailed it would be 1-p value. Am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: It depends on your hypotheses. What hypotheses are you using?

Comment: If I weigh 5 Kg more than you, do you weigh 5 Kg less than me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it's a two tailed test the p-value would stay the same.

You can think of it like this: When you do a t-test you look at the difference in mean between two samples, and then you balance that by how well that mean is estimated (the standard error of the mean). The standard error of the mean will depend on how many observations you have and how much your observations vary (standard deviation). $$standard\:error=\frac{standard\:deviation}{\sqrt{nr\:of\:observations}}$$

When you take $\frac{difference\:in\:means}{standard\:error}$ you get your t-score. So if you take $\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2$ instead of $\bar{x}_2-\bar{x}_1$ this will indeed flip the sign on the t-score, but not the magnitude. However, the p-value basically represents not-yet-covered-percentiles on the distribution of t-scores.

T-scores are assumed to become more normally distributed when the number of observations increases so just like you can get a percentile rank of someone's height you can get a percentile on the t-distribution i.e. how much of the area under the normally distributed curve you've covered. When we do a one-tailed test we count how much of the distribution we've covered from the bottom of the distribution (like with percentiles for height). When we do a two-tailed test we instead let the area we're covering expand from the mean. Since your t-score only flips sign, not magnitude, you would get the same p-value.

Comment: `T-scores are assumed to be normally distributed` Then what has a t-distribution?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it was a bit of a simplification. The t-distribution approaches the normal distribution as n goes towards infinity.